Error while making a Join to Create Feature for my Discord Bot
java: incompatible types: net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.channel.middleman.AudioChannel cannot be converted to net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.channel.concrete.VoiceChannel - This Error appears on 2 of my Lines:
(Line 29) 1: if ((joined = event.getChannelJoined()).getIdLong() == 1245716772519149590l) {
(Line 36) 2: VoiceChannel channel = event.getChannelLeft(); 
java: incompatible types: net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.channel.middleman.AudioChannel cannot be converted to net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.channel.concrete.VoiceChannel - on these 2:
(Line 42) 3: onJoin(event.getChannelLeft());
(Line 43) 4: onLeave(event.getChannelJoined());
Full Code:
package main.voice;

import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Guild;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Member;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.channel.concrete.Category;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.channel.concrete.VoiceChannel;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.channel.middleman.AudioChannel;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.guild.voice.GuildVoiceJoinEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.guild.voice.GuildVoiceLeaveEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.guild.voice.GuildVoiceMoveEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class voice extends ListenerAdapter {

    public List<Long> tempchannels;

    public voice() {

        this.tempchannels = new ArrayList<>();

    }

    @Override
    public void onGuildVoiceJoin (GuildVoiceJoinEvent event) {

        onJoin(event.getChannelJoined(), event.getEntity());

    }

    @Override
    public void onGuildVoiceLeave (GuildVoiceLeaveEvent event) {

        onLeave(event.getChannelLeft());

    }

    public void onGuildVoiceMove (GuildVoiceMoveEvent event) {

        onLeave(event.getChannelLeft());
        onJoin(event.getChannelJoined(), event.getEntity());

    }

    public void onJoin(VoiceChannel joined, Member member) {

        if (joined.getIdLong() == 1245716772519149590l) {

            Category cat = joined.getParentCategory();
            VoiceChannel vc = cat.createVoiceChannel(member.getEffectiveName() + "´s Voice").complete();
            vc.getGuild().moveVoiceMember(member, vc).queue();

            this.tempchannels.add(vc.getIdLong());

        }

    }

    public void onLeave(VoiceChannel channel) {

        if (channel.getMembers().size() <= 0) {

            if (this.tempchannels.contains(channel.getIdLong())) {

                this.tempchannels.remove(channel.getIdLong());
                channel.delete().queue();

            }

        }

    }

}



For VoiceChannel channel = event.getChannelLeft();  it should be  AudioChannel channel = event.getChannelLeft() as the error indicates.
See the source code
 @Nullable
    public AudioChannelUnion getChannelJoined()
    {
        return (AudioChannelUnion) next;
    }

public interface AudioChannelUnion extends AudioChannel

public interface VoiceChannel extends ISnowflake // Is an entity and no relation to AudioChannel


